# Do 朋 and 友 differ in meaning?

Tags: characters, difference

I've learned 朋友 as a unit for the word 'friend'. After looking the two characters up, I see that they both mean... *friend*.

It seems 友 is often used as the latter part of words expressing something with "friend", like 好友 for *good friend*.

**What is the difference between 朋 and 友?**

Do they have slightly different meanings when used separately, or are they identical in meaning and just used in different situations?

Comment: as dictionary entries for 朋 and 友 will show, they are both bound morphemes（粘着语素）(and 朋 possibly to a larger extent) as distinguished from free morphemes (自由语素），bound unlike free morphemes are not words (词).

Comment: At  小马词典 find 88 compounds with 友  and 23  with 朋, 11 成语 among them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a noun, both 朋 and 友 mean friends. While 朋 is mostly a noun, 友 is often be used as an adjective for 'friendly, ' as in '**友**軍'(**friendly** force); '**友**方'(**friendly** side)

**友** can also be a verb for '**befriend**' in classical sentences.

To find the subtle difference between two characters with similar meaning in a compound word, like 朋友，you can observe the other compound words they associate with.

Examples:

> 朋比為奸  friends collude in criminal acts
>
> 朋黨 circle (of friends); alliance (of friends)

*The phrases above show **朋** emphasis on the '**closeness**' and  '**alliance**' between  friends*

> 友善 (friendly), 友好 (friendly), 友愛 (friendship), 友誼 (friendship)

*The phrases above, show **友** emphasis on the ' **fondness**' and '**emotional tie**'  between friends'*

Comment: Very interesting to read your answer, it really cleared things up. Good suggestion to look at other compound words to get the "feeling" for a character!

Comment: You could add that foreigners will still find 友谊商店 in some cities, and the 友谊宾馆 is not at all a bad place to stay if your first trip to China includes Beijing.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think anyone would say '他是我的朋。' nowadays.

You might hear 他是我的好友。 or 他是我的好朋友。

Old 孔子 said, 有朋自远方来 不亦乐乎。 but that was a long time ago!

Apparently, 朋 represents the wings of a legendary bird, like a phoenix. Maybe that means it brings luck or joy, like a good friend and
友 represents 2 right hands, like 'he's my right hand, my friend' or 'holding hands'

Comment: Indeed, 老友 for instance is an expression I hear often (in the South anyway). I don't think anyone says 老朋.

Answer (score 5):

“志同为朋，道合为友，”
然而现代正常中国人并不区分朋和友，

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese, just the word "友" means a friend, and "朋" is a additive (or supplemental) character of meaning a friend (not used as a single word, for example"朋友", which is same as Chinese, I think). 
Perhaps it will help your understanding, and I will hope that will be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

“朋” refers to the those who share a same period of education experience(classmates, schoolmates) 朋->同学 classmate, 朋党 -> the alumni

"友“ refers to those who have the common interests or goals and trust each other 友->同志 comrade, friend

In《论语》, the compound word 朋友 appears “与朋友交而不信乎”. The usage is very similar to what we use nowadays in modern Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that 朋 (two moon radicals) implied two equal companions standing side by side, while 友 (left hand holding right hand) implied a more intimate (but not necessarily sexual) relationship.

Answer (score -1):

朋means those who share the same teacher 
「同師曰朋」《說文註》
友means those who share the same goal 
「同志曰友」